# Get current location from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

I have a method in my appDelegate which gets latitude and longitude and returns a string which I can use in any viewController.

**AppDelegate** :

```
-(void)StartUpdating
{    
    locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locManager.delegate = self;
    locManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark 
#pragma mark locationManager delegate methods 


- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation: (CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    float latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    strLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
    float longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    strLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", longitude];
    //[self returnLatLongString:strLatitude:strLongitude];

}

-(NSString*)returnLatLongString
{    
    NSString *str = @"lat=";
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:strLatitude];
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"&long="];
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:strLongitude];

    return str;
}
```

I am calling **StartUpdating** in start of application. Now in my viewController I call this method:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate=[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
NSString *str = [appDelegate returnLatLongString];
```

But I get a crash in

```
str = [str stringByAppendingString:strLatitude];
```

in `returnLatLongString`.

I know I am getting crash because there is no value in **strLatitude** at that time. But how can I fix this? How can I still have updated value of latitude and longitude?

Also, I don't want to use **locationManager** in viewControllers. So that I can get current location in all viewControllers, I did it in appDelegate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crash might be because `str` is an NSString, and so therefore is not mutable. Assigning it back to itself in this case is problematic. It would be simpler just to use `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"lat=%@&long=%@", strLatitude, strLongitude];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a mistake with creating a object of `AppDelegate` Class..

To create object just write this code :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *str = [appDelegate returnLatLongString];
```

Its done..

Comment: In `AppDelegate *appDelegate=[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];` I think the author did the right thing: to return the delegate from sharedApplication like `return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`.

Answer (score 0):

Import your AppDelegate.h file. Then
Use the following code:

```
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *result = [myAppDelegate returnLatLongString];
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to init those variables (strLatitude, strLongitude)  in your 
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method. if it hits this point at first time, they are not initialized so you get crash.

Comment: It's likely that the OP has defined strLatitude and strLongitude as ivars, otherwise the app wouldn't build in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems in your code.

First of all make sure you declare `strLatitude` and `strLongitude` as `strong` properties in your header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * strLatitude;    
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * strLongitude;
```

Use `@synthesize` to automatically generate the proper getter and setter for them and assign the proper values to them as:

```
float latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
self.strLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
float longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
self.strLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", longitude];
```

to make sure that they don't get released after they are assigned a value, because `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` returns `autoreleased` objects.

Secondly, after `[locManager startUpdatingLocation];` it's going to take sometime before the system delivers the first location update. Therefore you need to check if the `strLatitude` and `strLongitude` have already been assigned values before you try to construct another string with them. Something similar to this should do the job:

```
-(NSString*)returnLatLongString
{
    if (self.strLatitude == nil || self.strLongitude == nil)
        return nil;

    NSString *str = @"lat=";
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:strLatitude];
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"&long="];
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:strLongitude];

    return str;
}
```

Then of course the view controllers who are going to use `[AppDelegate returnLatLongString]` need to check that the returned value is not `nil`.

Hope this helps...